# highlight command refuses to change theme

Tags: command-line, text-formatting

```
$ highlight -l -s clarity -S sh -O ansi some_file
```

No matter what I try, highlight always shows the same theme. And it is supposed to create a file 'highlight.css' but it doesn't.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `-O ansi`, the output will consist of ANSI escape sequences which would  colorize the output in your shell.

The `highlight.css` file is created for HTML, XHTML, and SVG outputs.

Using `-O html` should get you your desired results:

```bash
$ highlight -l -s clarity -S sh -O html some_file
```

(Note that you could use the `-o` flag to save the output in a file and use the `-I` flag to include the styles in the output as opposed to in a separate highlight.css file)

Comment: Thanks!  Sheesh the man page might say that the style can't change with ANSI.  As it is I'm only wanting ANSI output.  I wonder, is there some other highlighter that would work with ANSI?

Comment: @RayAndrews You're correct that `highlight` doesn't support themes with ANSI. If I had to guess, that would probably be due to how limited they are (8 - 16 colors) compared to xterm-256 (which by the way works with themes in `highlight`). Unfortunately I don't know any tools that that support custom syntax highlighting for just 3-4 bit ANSI colors. If your terminal supports 256 colors, you should just go with `-O xterm256` with `highlight`.

Comment: Thing is I have to export to a program that only accepts ANSI so downgrading would be needed, but it seems there's no converter.

Comment: @RayAndrews I see. I couldn't really find any tools that converted from xterm-256 colors to ANSI. So I quickly built [xterm2ansi](https://github.com/zaidhaan/xterm2ansi). Pipe your highlight output to that and it should work. (Fair warning, I'm not a good C programmer so there may be a few bugs, feel free to send any PRs)

Comment: Cool!  Stand by for a review.